# Is it correct to say "don't let it trouble you"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I am wondering if it is correct to use the sentence "*Don't let it trouble you.*"
Would native speakers find it natural?

Comment: Downvote, really? For what? I am asking about the usage of a phrase and its correctness...also both LANGUAGE AND USAGE...and not, it is not basic because this is nothing a book can tell you..

Comment: IANTDV, but perhaps the DV thought you put little research effort into this (since none is shown) and that the question is unclear (since it is unclear), and upon reading “This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful” next to the downvote arrow, decided to downvote.

Comment: I did a research and Google has shown only 105K records and mainly in translator sites, which is not much credible really. WHat is unclear on a question asking "is that correct? Would a native speaker find it natural?". Anyway, got the anwers, thanks

Comment: TerryS, re  “What is unclear on a question asking "is that correct? ..."”, your  original form didn't say what *that* referred to.  The question has since been edited and *that* is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is correct to say so assuming the 'it' here is known or understood by the people involved in the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I can confirm that this is a correct and natural saying.

Comment: To follow up; usually the action or object is referenced instead of using "it" (e.x. "Dont let this quandary bother you").